# Classifying GPS locations according to Land area classification using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, classification

I have a vector layer for the GPS locations and a raster for the landuse/landcover. I've realized a supervised classification to classify the categories in the Lulc and a maximum likelihood classification (even though I do not know if this last step was useful).

The ideal would be to have a table with the number of location points found for each categories. Like this I can have a percentage, in which categorie ( ex forest) we found 56 locations so 21% for example.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python solution:

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\temp\landcover.shp'

# Get a list of all the cover types
vals = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "cover")]

# Loop through unique cover values and calculate percentage of total
for val in set(vals):
    percent = float(vals.count(val))/float(len(vals)) * 100
    print "{0} {1}%".format(val, percent)
```

[image]

---

```
>>> 
grassland 10.0%
urban 10.0%
deciduous 20.0%
conifer 60.0%
>>>
```